# how to add speech for dynamically generated textbox in winforms c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created one winform app in which, on click of button, **textbox** will be generated. Now I have to add **speech** for these textboxes. For example if textbox's text is 'hello' there will be speech saying 'hello'.

I have tried this so far. :

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    int count = panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count;
    textbox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 25 * count);
    textbox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 20);
    textbox.Multiline = true;
    textbox.Name = "textbox_" + (count + 1);
    //textbox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_Changed);
    panel1.Controls.Add(textbox);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SpVoice vc = new SpVoice();
    vc.Speak(textbox1.Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
}
```

I am using **speechLib** library for speech. Working fine in simple cases.

But when textbox is being created dynamically, I cannot access its ID or Name.

Comment: It is not clear if the added textbox is in the same form where the button is present. If this is the case then it is not possible to use a not existent textbox in the form load event. Could you clarify this point?

Comment: yes. textbox and the button are in the same form @Steve

Comment: But then in the form_load event the TextBox doesn't exist. You can't use it. Perhaps you need a different button that executes the code currently in the Form_Load event

Comment: then also same problem will be there. i cannot access these textbox in my back end code. @Steve

Comment: could you not just move the code in Form1_load to brnAddClick?

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox is created in the button click event, then in the form_load event it doesn't exist, so you cannot use it as input for your voice library.

However, when you create the TextBox you could add a value for the property Tag.
For example

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    .....
    textbox.Name = "textbox_" + (count + 1);
    textbox.Tag = "SPEECH";
    ....
    panel1.Controls.Add(textbox);
}
```

Now, when you need to retrieve this dynamically created textbox and use your voice library you could write this. But for the example I use an event handler for a different button

```
private void AnotherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = panel1.Controls
                        .OfType<TextBox>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x =x.Tag.ToString() == "SPEECH");

    if (txt != null)
    {
        SpVoice vc = new SpVoice();
        vc.Speak(txt.Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Press the create button first!");
    }
}
```

If you want, you could also use the same button event handler. Check if the control with the specified Tag exists and if not create it, if yes execute the voice Speak call.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = panel1.Controls
                        .OfType<TextBox>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(x =x.Tag.ToString() == "SPEECH");

    if (txt != null)
    {
        SpVoice vc = new SpVoice();
        vc.Speak(txt.Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        .....
        textbox.Name = "textbox_" + (count + 1);
        textbox.Tag = "SPEECH";
        ....
        panel1.Controls.Add(textbox);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This assumes there is only one textbox with the SPEECH tag set. If you want more than one textbox then you should be able to tell which one you want to 'talk' (adding a little button on the right side of the textbox with a speaker image?) or loop over all the textboxes with the SPEECH tag and call Speak for each one

Something like this

```
var speechBoxes = panel1.Controls
                  .OfType<TextBox>()
                  .Where(x =x.Tag.ToString() == "SPEECH");

if (speechBoxes != null)
{
    SpVoice vc = new SpVoice();

    foreach(TextBox txt in speechBoxes)
    {
        vc.Speak(txt.Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);

        // Not sure if you need also to add this call ....
        vc.WaitUntilDone(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course not. This assumes there is only one textbox with speech. If you want more than one textbox then you should be able to tell which one you want to 'talk' or loop over all the textboxes with the SPEECH tag and call Speak for each one.